# Can the amount of files in a directoy make the read operation slower for one of the files?

Tags: directory, operation, file-read

I have a directory with 10 million files inside. I want to read a file of this dir without testing if it exists or not in the dir.

Will this operation be affected by other files?

Comment: May depend on the OS / file system. But then again, maybe it doesn't matter much whether you check for a file with `exist` or with `open`. What do you want to do if the files does not exist? Can you explain the background of your question?